# YouTube iFrame has intermittent load errors

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

Our software allows users to mix various media, including YouTube videos, together in a sequential timeline. We are intermittently seeing errors with loading YouTube videos loading in our player. We use the youtube iframe API. We first manually create the YouTube embed iframe, and then instantiate the YouTube iframe API, passing in the iframe.

When this issue happens, it manifests itself as follows: The YouTube player is a black screen with the loading symbol. It stays in that state for about a minute (sometimes more) and eventually gives the error: "An error occured, please try again later", although sometimes the player just stays black indefinitely. During this minute wait, we have inspected the "Stats for Nerds" panel and see that the video seems to begin a cycle of loading different resolutions. You can see this occur beginning around the 1:00 mark of this video:

https://www.cubby.com/pl/Instant+meeting+2013-12-31.webm/_8cbafbaed7c64d828b260b41cd9db8dc

We see it cycle through such resolutions as:

426 x 240

256 x 144

854 x 480

1280 x 720

When this happens, almost always, the video plays fine after refreshing the page and trying again.We have seen it happen on solid, high speed connections as well as lower speed connections.

Here's the iframe code snagged right from the DOM when the error was occurring:

`<iframe id="youtube_iframe" type="text/html" width="100%" height="375" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/FCuq3IedO9k?allowScriptAccess=always&controls=0&disablekb=1&enablejsapi=1&playsinline=1&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=1&start=151&rel=0&vq=large&showinfo=0&wmode=opaque&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.meograph.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

Any ideas on why this could be happening or ideas on how to prevent it from happening would be very helpful. If you'd like any additional debug information (I have a screenshot of the network panel from a time this happened, for example), just let me know and I'll link it.

Comment: This appears to be a bug report rather than a question about programming with the YouTube API.

Comment: +1 - You will want to log YouTube API bugs at the link below (link from youtube.com/dev): https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20(Defect%20Report)

Comment: You may try to force video quality with their api https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Playback_quality

Answer (score 1):

Your link is not working -

https://www.youtube.com/embed/FCuq3IedO9k?allowScriptAccess=always&controls=0&disablekb=1&enablejsapi=1&playsinline=1&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=1&start=151&rel=0&vq=large&showinfo=0&wmode=opaque&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.meograph.com

Try to use this kind of code

```
<iframe width="420" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/oHg5SJYRHA0?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```